# Refreshing $scope for ng repeat

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am making an Angular App with using twitch api. What I must to do for refreshing ng repeat scope($scope.players), after async ajax call?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,TwitchFactory) {
$scope.channels = channels;
$scope.players = [];
handlePlayers();

function handlePlayers() {
    var player;

    var length = channels.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        switch (channels[i].serviceId) {
        case '3': 
            TwitchFactory.getPlayer(channels[i]).done(function(data) {
                if(data.stream) {
                    player = {};
                    player.game = data.stream.game;

                    $scope.players.push(player);
                }
            });
        break;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngRepeat` directive has own watchers and you don't need to care about model update. However be sure that `getPlayer`  fires digest cycle.

I suggest you helper factory that should check if  digest cycle is running:

```
   app.factory('UtilsFactory', ['$rootScope' function($rootScope) {

       return {
            isScopeInCycle: function() {
                return $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' &&
                       $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
            }
}
```

The usage:

- add factory to controller and use as:

---

```
 function handlePlayers() {
    var player;

    var length = channels.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        switch (channels[i].serviceId) {
        case '3': 
            TwitchFactory.getPlayer(channels[i]).done(function(data) {
                if(data.stream) {
                    player = {};
                    player.game = data.stream.game;

                    $scope.players.push(player);

                    if (UtilsFactory.isScopeInCycle()) {
                       $rootScope.$apply(function() {                    
                        $scope.players.push(player);

                       });
                      }
                      else{
                        $scope.players.push(player);
                      }
                }
            });
        break;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.So what the reason of models not updating?

Comment: Does `$apply` helped you?

Comment: Ok, in basic words, angular updates all DOM elements automatically by using digest sycle. Sometimes 3d party plugins do not fire digest cycle and angular doesn't know that change is done. In your case `TwitchFactory.getPlayer`. So we need to fire digest cycle by own.